# how to find unique items in a total data set

Tags: python, collections, unique

I have a data set with around 60,000 rows. It is a purchase order where you do not have a unique ID. Sample data below.

```
36 40 41 42 43 45 46
38 39 48 50 51 57
41 59 62
63 66 67 68
74 75 76 77
```

In the above list each number is an item purchased. I need the following:

1. Total unique items in the data set.
2. Top 5 items which were most purchased.

Comment: That's the exact format of the file? And you want to ignore the rows really, and just focus on the items, right?

Comment: Yes this is the format of the file.Actually the data in the file starts from 36 40 41....i have just included row1, row2 for understanding and yes focus is  on the items alone. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. I updated my answer, but you should just include the actual file in your question; don't add `rowX`.

Comment: @Cyphase, got the result finally. Earlier I have given the path as "D:\scripts\file.txt" which resulted in error. Now I changed it to "D:/scripts/file.txt" which has given the result. But can you please let me know what makes the difference between " \ " and " / " .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from collections import Counter

items = Counter()
with open('data_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items.update(line.split())

print("Total Unique Items: {0}".format(len(items)))

for item, count in items.most_common(5):
    print("Item {0} was purchased {1} times".format(item, count))
```

Yes, it's that short :).

Comment: I tried executing the same script as above but I am getting an error message as OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:                                           only change made in the script is the path of the file.I am very much new to python so finding it difficult to debug..

Comment: @Yash, you have to specify the actual file you want to read from.

Comment: I have given my file path location with the file extension but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Yash, hmm.. perhaps time to ask another question :). Post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you dataset is a csv file or a text file.

```
from collections import Counter

with open(path, "r") as fp:
    raw = fp.readlines()

purchases = [item for line in raw for item in line.split()]
print "Unique ids: %s" %(len(set(purchases))
print "Most purchased ids:" %(",".join([ item[1] for item in Counter(purchases).most_common(5)]))
```

The above code should give your results.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total length of the list, iterate through the rows using a loop and add each integer to a Python list using `list.append(x)` with the condition that `if x not in list` to get rid of the duplicates. Then, sort the list using `list.sort()`. Finally, do `len(list)`.

To get the top 5 most purchased items, again iterate through the rows using a loop, but this time add all of the integers to a list, regardless of duplicates. Then do `collections.Counter(list).most_common(5)[0][0]`.

See the Python list docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) and the collections docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

Comment: This wouldn't give you the most purchased items.

Comment: @Cyphase right, I misread the question. I modified my answer. Using collections.Counter is the best way.

Comment: That still wouldn't work, since you're getting rid of the duplicates before passing the list to `Counter()`. Also, don't use `list` as a variable name :).

Comment: @Cyphase, I'm not checking for duplicates in the second loop iteration, so I'm not getting rid of the duplicates. Right about the list though :)

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that you were iterating again :).